# Why doesn't SMPS controller VCC capacitor get fully charged to 310 V?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, ac-dc

Most SMPS circuits have a startup circuit like the one in the schematic below:

[image: Flyback example]

The rectified 310 V goes through Rstartup1 and Rstartup2 to fill Cvcc to UVLO limit and the controller IC starts working. But the interesting thing is, the VCC is still connected to 310 V via resistors and the Cvcc must continue charging to 310 V which must blow the IC.

I first thought the current was very small and thus consumed by the IC but then I realized the IC gets its energy from the aux winding after it has started. Even if this wasn't the case, the IC may still give an error and stop working, thus all the current would flow to Cvcc. I believe commercial standards wouldn't allow this kind of security issue. So what am I getting wrong, can you explain?

I've one more question for this schematic. Why are Qsc and Q1 necessary? Qsc interferes with current sense and Q1 just has no use to my eyes. Q1 would turn on at start up and stay on forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This circuit is built around the venerable UC384x which consumes a high start-up current, 1 mA as a max. The power-on process is as follows:

1. The power supply is connected to the mains and a high-voltage appears across the front-end *bulk* capacitor. This voltage ranges from 120 V dc up to 375 V dc in a universal mains application (\$V_{in}\$ goes from 85 V to 265 V rms).
2. The \$V_{cc}\$ capacitor is fully discharged and its voltage starts rising owing to the start-up resistors connected in series to the high-voltage rail. However, as the voltage across the capacitor increases, the integrated circuit wakes up and absorbs some current, up to 1 mA. Therefore, the start-up resistors must be sized so that this current is delivered even at the lowest input.
3. The charging process continues and the driver output is kept to 0 V, nothing pulses.
4. When the \$V_{cc}\$ reaches the turn-on level (usually 10-12 V), the circuit starts delivering pulses and more current is absorbed considering the energy to actuate the MOSFET. As a result, and with a newly-absorbed current above that of the supplied current from the start-up resistors, the \$V_{cc}\$ drops quickly towards the under-voltage lockout level (UVLO), 7-8 V, which is the minimum acceptable \$V_{cc}\$ under which the IC stops operating.
5. Before reaching the UVLO, the power supply had time to increase the output voltage (in normal conditions of course) and the turn-off plateau at the \$D_{aux}\$ anode is already high, high enough to take over and keep the \$V_{cc}\$ alive, stopping the collapse.
6. The power supply continues its start-up sequence until \$V_{out}\$ reaches its target and the feedback loop takes control. Please note that if the \$V_{cc}\$ is internally clamped by a internal Zener diode of 34 V (typical), the DRV pin is not and you must limit the aux voltage below the maximum \$V_{GS}\$, usually 20 V. In practice, the aux is set around 13-15 V.

Below is a typical start-up sequence excerpted from my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468) on SMPS:

[image]

The main drawback of this approach is the high dissipation budget brought by the start-up resistors. You understand that sizing them for slightly more than 1 mA at low line implies a much higher current in high-line condition hence an enormous dissipated power. These were the times of the burnt PCBs because of these resistors : ) Nowadays, start-up current of low-voltage controllers are around ten µA (see NCP12510 for instance) or even better, they can be directly connected to the HV rail via a dedicated current source which is turned off after the start-up sequence.

Now, regarding the transistors you mentioned:

\$Q_{sc}\$: this transistor is connected as a voltage follower (common emitter) and is there to buffer the oscillator sawtooth. A part of this buffered ramp is added to the current sense information and it feeds the controller CS pin input. This is a complicated subject but, in a nutshell, current-mode power supplies are subject to sub-harmonic instabilities when the duty ratio approaches and exceeds 50% in continuous conduction mode (CCM). You can observe this phenomenon by looking at the DRV pin with an oscilloscope and observing alternating truncated pulses whose recurrence is half the switching frequency. I published a [paper](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/2101/articles/H2PToday2101_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) in [How2Power](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/index.php) some time ago on the subject if you want to know more.

Please note that this compensation method can bring noise to the power supply as you touch a sensitive portion of the circuit with low currents which is the oscillator. A more robust option is to connect an \$RCD\$ network to the low-impedance DRV pin as documented by Ridley in the 90's and depicted in slide 80 of my [APEC 2018](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202018.pdf) seminar.

\$Q_1\$: this transistor serves two purposes in my opinion. The first one is to limit the voltage at the TL431 cathode in case of a high output voltage. It is a simple linear regulator. The second is to turn the fast lane off and, again, it is a complicated matter implying the regulation mechanism of the TL431 coupled with an optocoupler. I invite you to look at a [presentation](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/The%20TL431%20in%20Switching%20Power%20Supplies.pdf) I built some years ago on the subject.

Now, I don't know the role of the Zener diode around the opto LED, like it would protect the diode in case of fault somewhere in the loop? Never seen this before and I'm not even sure it is correctly connected (the label 700 mV/2 A is meaningless).

Comment: I would still add a zener diode to VCC pin which is below ablosulte max voltage rating. I'm thinking of using UCC28740 instead. It has integrated HV startup. Also, it has variable frequency which increases efficiency on light loads. I guess modern power supplies implement one or more of the following: valley switching (or quasi-resonant I guess they are the same thing?), ZVS and variable frequency. Also thanks for the transistor explanations, I'll read the paper when I focus on the control part.

Comment: I have rarely seen a Zener diode across the \$V_{cc}\$ pin but it does not harm if you want to add one. Make sure though that its min voltage does not interfere with the max of the IC startup source turn-off voltage. Some circuits implement an over-voltage protection (OVP) and the \$V_{cc}\$ must run away for detection so you may want to check this. Yes, frequency foldback to improve the performance in light-load conditions.

Answer (score 4):

The chip has an internal Zener diode to limìt overvoltage.

The chip starts at 16V and turns off at 10V.

The resistor is chosen so that it can charge the capacitor up to 16V but then chip current consumption is so large that the resistor can't provide enough current and voltage starts to drop, but the capacitor is large enough to keep the chip running until the switching provides chip supply from the auxiliary winding.